# how to set custom line.separator in jasper report text exporter

Tags: jasper-reports

I am trying to set the line.separator property using the below property in jrxml file.

```
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.text.line.separator" value="\r\n"/>
```

But, It is printing **"\r\n"** in my output file, instead of **carriage-return and line-feed**. What is missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I had to use XML entities to get the desired behavior. Hope this helps.

```
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.record.delimiter" value="&#x0D;&#x0A;"/>
```

Comment: <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.text.line.separator" value="&#x0D;&#x0A;"/>

Source:
http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/531981/changing-csv-record-delimiter